# Help with some handwritten letter

Tags: letter, handwriting

I bought a watch on eBay and got this letter. I asked the seller "what does it say?", but got no answer. Can anyone help?  Regards!!

[image: LETTER]

Comment: at least a rotated version?

Comment: The letter appears to have been written by a buyer not a seller. This does not fit with the context you have given.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

> Hallo Herr Sch(1),
>
> war das nicht ein schönes Gespräch nach der verständlichen Aufregung
> auf *beiden* Seiten.
>
> Nun freue ich mich auf die [»Lange und Söhne«](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/A._Lange_%26_S%C3%B6hne) und hoffe, wirklich eine gute
> Uhr gekauft zu haben.
>
> Mit freundlichen Grüßen
>
> (2)

(1) Schoiber?

(2) Ida x?

Comment: (1) Schorker? (2) Frida Fi...?

Comment: You Pollitzer sir are the best!!! thanks!!